# Google Maps Android API Authorization failure - has this service changed in the last few months?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, authorization, xamarin

I have coded a Xamarin Google Apps V2 application. The device I am deploying to has Google Play Services installed.

The application has all been setup correctly in the API console and I have had this application working before, months ago.

Currently, when the application is deployed to my device, I am getting the following errors in the Application output:

> [Google Maps Android API] Authorization failure.  Please see
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how
>   to correctly set up the map.
>
> [Google Maps Android API] Ensure that the following correspond to what
>   is in the API Console: [**My API key data**]
>
> [Google Maps Android API] Failed to contact Google servers. Another
>   attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
>
> [Google Maps Android API] Failed to load map. Error contacting Google
>   servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to
>   network errors).

I have not changed the code from months ago when it was working, yet, as you can see above, the Google Maps component is not loading correctly.

Why would this be? Has there been a change to the Google API in the last few months? How can I get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This error came when your Map API key not Authorized with your Pkg. so kindly generate a New key and check

Comment: I have generated a new key, added this key to the AndroidManifest.xml and have run the application. I am still getting the same Authorization failure.

Comment: Has there been a change to the authorization system in the last few months?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I have exactly the same problem. Nothing I'm trying works. Changing keystore doesn't work. Changing package doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from this question solved my problem with this. I had the exact same issue!

[Google maps suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805769/google-maps-suddenly-not-working)