# Google maps suddenly not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

All of a sudden maps stopped working in my app and just shows a blank screen with the google logo in the bottom left corner.

The error I get is:

```
I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 4452038
I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.google.android.gms.maps for service com.google.android.gms/.maps.auth.ApiTokenService: 
I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 4452000
I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

The only think I believe is possible is an authentication error. Since I've tried on different networks and have not troubles there.

Could the problem be with the build.gradle file? Because the problems started after I messed around there, i think.

This is my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def value = 0

    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
        value = 1;
    }

    def versionMajor = 1
    def versionMinor = 3
    def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
    def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
    def version_Code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value

    versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = version_Code.toString()

    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode version_Code
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild})"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("xxx.keystore")
        storePassword "xxxx"
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword "xxxx"
    }
    releaseKey {
        storeFile file("xxx.keystore")
        storePassword "xxxx"
        keyAlias "release"
        keyPassword "xxxx"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseKey
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':nineOldAndroids')
    compile project(':expListViewLib')
    compile project(':datetimepickerlibrary')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.1.jar')
}
```

the manifest looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app" >

<permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ...

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/config_com.google.android.maps.v2.api_key" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

I have checked multiple times that packageName, sha1 fingerprint and API is correct. All of them are, but I still get an empty map.

I've seen similar questions out there but none of the solutions I found. It just refuses to work for me.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Nothing that I have tried works. But I did find a similar question with someone who seems to have the same problem: [Google Maps Android API Authorization failure - has this service changed in the last few months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466789/google-maps-android-api-authorization-failure-has-this-service-changed-in-the)

Comment: Is it happening to both sign (debug and release)?

Comment: @betorcs yup, not working on any of them even if I add the debug to the google api panel.

Comment: I read in somewhere it can be proguard misconfigured, try disable it `runProguard false`

Comment: I could reproduce this error. It looks app cache you api_key, i needed clean data or uninstall existing app, only override wasn't enough.

Comment: @betorcs thanks for your response. I tried to disable proguard and deleting the app before installing and I still have the problem. I also re-created the api key and still no luck. I find it really strange.

Comment: Yep it's really strange, this message use to be shown when key is wrong, Lets try two more things, #1 renames `config_com.google.android.maps.v2.api_key` to `map_api_key`, #2 renames package name from `com.example.app` another one. And keep in mind debuggable version has `.debug` in the end show the package'll be  `com.example.app.debug`, then in google api console you need put `[fingerprint];com.example.app.debug`

Comment: @betorcs I've tried all the things you mentioned without luck. I've also tried changing keystore, removing any additions to the packagename .debug and still nothing.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I can totally repro this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and the solution was not obvious at all. Check if you are not changing DefaultSSLSocketFactory with:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Removing this line and setting socket factory just for the required connection made my maps work.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much! How did you figure it out?

Comment: Almost accidentally. During debugging and digging through the project, in which maps were not working, I found https address used by google for authentication. I came up with the idea to check connection properties and that was a good shot.

Comment: Could you please provide the details? Where is located that code? "HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());"

Comment: It was in my class responsible for the HTTPS connection. Before creating the connection socket.

Comment: Can you please make a better explanation with code example to correct this problem? My maps is not working because of my connection handling, I have tested it but I can't figure how to keep the SSL just for my own server's connections