# Google maps on Android not working on app but demo is fine

Tags: android, google-maps

I cannot get Google Maps to work on my app.

I see a blank screen; no grids show, only the google logo and the +/- zoom buttons.

**What I have done:**

- I have the "Google Maps Android API v2" API enabled
- I have added my project along with the demo project to the API credential list on Google console
- I've also added the required permissions for Internet, location, com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
- Even added the "MAPS_RECEIVE" permission as some posts suggested
- Also added the 'meta-data' google_play_services_version

Since the demos are working, I literally copied MultiMapDemoActivity and its files into my project and tried opening map, to no avail.

The problem may be linked to [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=7188) issue. However, it seems like they can't get map to work at all.

Here is the interesting bit that I noticed, I usually get this:

```
10-02 12:29:20.376: D/REQUEST(5826): Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-02 12:29:20.376: D/REQUEST(5826): Open Connection
```

Followed by this:

```
10-02 12:21:45.361: D/REQUEST(5826): DRD(80): 62|132
10-02 12:21:45.361: D/REQUEST(5826): Close
10-02 12:21:45.361: D/REQUEST(5826): Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@42caa7b8 not retrying
10-02 12:21:45.361: D/REQUEST(5826): Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.a@4296a530
```

- Also, not sure if this is relevant, but as soon as I click to open the map, or click on the map after it has opened and is showing a blank view, I see this:

  ```
    10-02 13:03:32.978: E/DatabaseUtils(15468): Writing exception to parcel
    10-02 13:03:32.978:/DatabaseUtils(15468): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this   
    requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
  ```

---

**EDIT #1**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

---

**EDIT #2**
Also, the declared package name was com.A.B.C (the manifest); whereas the activities of my project had the structure of com.A.B..

I have since updated my project structure to match that of the manifest, but I still see the same errors as before, nothing changes. I'm really at sea here, since I cannot understand what could be going wrong here.

---

Some help to resolve this will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a permission issue. Check that you have all the necessary permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: I've added the permissions on my project in the edit

Comment: I got the same problem, but I cannot get it to work on the debug mode, i.e. unreleased version.

Comment: did you replace map key with your map key key

Comment: @Gaurav, yes, already, triple checked and tried with various keys

Comment: @Hahn when i was developing maps for my app i was taking reference  from  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ please take a look may be you are missing something

Comment: In my case, the problem was the use of `applicationIdSuffix '.d'` in my Gradle build file for debug builds. This transformed the package name from `com.foo.bar` to `com.foo.bar.d` which invalidated my API key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had read n-1 questions regarding this issue here. Finally, after continuous searching everywhere, I stumbled upon the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805769/google-maps-suddenly-not-working) by @Jack.

Basically the line:`"HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(...)"` was the culprit in my code. I commented it out and everything worked fine.

NOTE: I have not tried to keep the line of code and modify it to make maps work yet. If I need/do it, I'll post a comment.

Comment: 2 days searching for an answer and then saw this! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your SHA1 fingerprint to the public API access.
Go to eclipse > preferences. Android > build and copy your default eclipse SHA1 fingerprint.

Now go to https://console.developers.google.com select your app, 'APIs and auth' > 'credentials' > and click on 'Edit allowed android applications' put your SHA1 figerfirnt like that:

XX:XX:XX:XX:XX...XX;com.your.pakage.app

Comment: Have done that already. In fact I've tried different keys (and added their SHA1 on google's console). The problem doesn't even change. I'm stuck with the same problem as before...

Comment: Is there any way of checking the SHA1 with Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

What about your google key? This line in the Manifest file:

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 ....`

I am also struggling with such behavior constantly. The first thing you want to verify in such situations is that your key from debug.keystore file is indeed the one that you registered with Google. This key will be used when you are debugging your application locally.

Note, however, you will need another keystore file when you release your application. At the time of signing, you should create another keystore, and register it too with Google.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and it took me so much hours to resolve it, at last I've done these steps and it worked finally!

- Do the same steps as it followed here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
- Use the debug certificate fingerprint if you're testing your project instead of the release certificate which you use when you install your app in the play store.
- Don't forget to add the value of the Google API and replace the "API_VALUE" with it.
- Change your project build target into Google APIs: Project>properties>android>target.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

These are the permissions you need according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions) documentation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I recommend you to include this too:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: I just added the permission I have, and yes, the feature is also included

Answer (score -3):

Add those in your manifest file

```
<permission
    android:name="xxx.xxxx.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxxx.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxxx.xxxx.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

replace `xxx.xxxx.xxxx` with your package name

Comment: I added the permission, though it is not supposed to be required in the v2. Still not change.